# Swift: How to convert AVAudioEngine's stereo output to mono

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I´m trying to convert the output of my AVAudioEngine from stereo to mono. I want to be able to send the converted mono signal to the left or right headphone or speaker using AVAudioPlayerNode's pan property.

```
engine.connect(audioFilePlayer[i], to: timePitchControl[i], format: audioFile[i].processingFormat)
engine.connect(timePitchControl[i], to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile[i].processingFormat)
```

Is there a way to convert the output of the engine (AVAudioEngine -> engine.mainMixerNode) to a mono signal in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Using a matrix mixer node it's possible. There are other ways but I am not aware of a simpler solution. A matrix mixer is a mixer that allows to connect any input to any output. So it can be used to connect left and right input channels to one output channel only.

#### Gist

Its usage is a bit complicated so I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ABridoux/fa31bb912cc5504e51f50a5b8a6d0fa0) to make it more convenient.

Here are some parts anyway.

### Instantiation

```swift
let matrixUnitDescription = AudioComponentDescription(
    componentType: kAudioUnitType_Mixer,
    componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixMixer,
    componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
    componentFlags: 0,
    componentFlagsMask: 0
)
let matrixMixerNode = try await AVAudioUnit.instantiate(with: matrixUnitDescription)
```

### Connect

You can then connect your player node to this mixer node, and connect the mixer node to the main mixer node (or another node before that if you prefer).

```swift
engine.connect(playerNode, to: matrixMixerNode, format: nil)
engine.connect(matrixMixerNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
```

Then comes the trick part. *When the engine is started*, set the general, input and output volumes:

```swift
// global
AudioUnitSetParameter(
    matrixMixerNode.audioUnit,
    kMatrixMixerParam_Volume, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
    0xFFFF_FFFF,
    1, 
    0
)

// inputs
for inputChannelIndex in 0..<matrixMixerNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).channelCount {
    AudioUnitSetParameter(
        matrixMixerNode.audioUnit,
        kMatrixMixerParam_Volume,
        kAudioUnitScope_Input,
        inputChannelIndex,
        1,
        0
    )
}

// outputs
for outputChannelIndex in 0..<matrixMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0).channelCount {
    AudioUnitSetParameter(
        matrixMixerNode.audioUnit,
        kMatrixMixerParam_Volume,
        kAudioUnitScope_Output,
        outputChannelIndex,
        volume,
        0
    )
}
```

And finally you can set the volume for a connexion between an input channel and an output channel. So, to transform a stereo signal to mono:

```swift
let leftCrossPoint = UInt32((0 << 16) | 0)
AudioUnitSetParameter(
    matrixMixerNode.audioUnit,
    kMatrixMixerParam_Volume,
    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
    leftCrossPoint,
    1,
    0
)

let rightCrossPoint = UInt32((1 << 16) | 0)
AudioUnitSetParameter(
    matrixMixerNode.audioUnit,
    kMatrixMixerParam_Volume,
    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
    rightCrossPoint,
    1,
    0
)
```

It's a lot of boiler plate, and here the volume was always 1 but it can also be adjusted. That's why the gist could be helpful if you need further details.

### Links

Anyway, here are the links I used to understand how to use this audio unit:

- https://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2008/Apr/msg00169.html
- [How should an AUMatrixMixer be configured in an AVAudioEngine graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059405/how-should-an-aumatrixmixer-be-configured-in-an-avaudioengine-graph)
- [Change audio volume of some channels using AVAudioEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208006/change-audio-volume-of-some-channels-using-avaudioengine)